# Using Kubuntu, Cant set up Java 8 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu

In Eclipse I do not have option java 8 in new project and java -version

java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

says I have 8 installed. I am running Kubuntu 14.04 and installed java 8 through the repositories.

Here is the snaphot that show that I cannot compile in java 8 ... :

[image: http://93.103.24.231/snapshot1.png]

Comment: did my answer help you or solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't have built-in support for J8. We have to wait until Luna comes next month.

However you can install it by marketplace.

Hope to help

[image]